# Regex for two or more, consecutive or non-consecutive uppercase letters

Tags: javascript, regex

A string (>=8 characters in length) must contain at least:

1. One lowercase letter
2. Two uppercase letters
3. One digit (0-9)
4. One special character from the following: `! @ # $ % ^ &`

Consecutive or non-consecutive. For instance, these need to be valid:

```
aBB1@

aBcB1@
```

invalid:

`aBc1@` (only one uppercase)

**The regex I have now:**

```
/^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#!@$%^&]).{8,}$/
```

How do I check for 2 or more, consecutive or non-consecutive uppercase letters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z].*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#!@$%^&]).{8,}$
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. What if i needed 10 of that? Would I need to write that 10 times? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your requirements none of your examples should have passed as none of them are 8 or more characters long.

That being said, I also think you can drop the lazy quantifier and use a repeated non-capture group, for example:

```
^(?=(?:.*[A-Z]){2})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[#!@$%^&]).{8,}$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tIoGPw/1).